# SDE boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, heat-equation, stochastic-differential-equations

So the probability density of Brownian motion on $\mathbb{R}$ is described by the heat equation on $\mathbb{R}$. So the Brownian motion is the SDE corresponding to the heat equation PDE.

How do we know what is the SDE corresponding to the heat equation on $[0,1]$ with Dirichlet or Neumann boundary conditions? I saw somewhere that that the Neumann BCs might correspond to a reflecting boundary for the SDE? Is this true for other PDEs (say,  Fokker-Planck or reaction-diffusion equation)?

Comment: Unlike a PDE, an SDE has no boundary condition. In short: for a Brownian motion $W_t$ the process $|W_t|$ is the BM reflected at zero and is related to a PDE with Neumann boundary conditions. See Karatzas & Shreve, *Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus*.